# Angular NgForm with two components

Tags: angular, html, angularjs-ng-form

I am trying to do a form with two different components. One parent and one child. I looked into a lot of tutorials and they all talked about doing a service.

However, I found a method on this [website](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475). It consists in adding the following in the child component:

```
viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
```

This method is quite nice but I would like to use:

```
[(ngModel)]="experiment.name"
```

and not just

```
ngModel
```

Here is the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-pierbjx) that I tried to run using this method.

Thank you for help

Comment: What is `experiment.name` in your code?

Comment: now you want to get the value of child component in parent component ?

Comment: In app.cmponent.html  `<address [experiment]=experiment></address>`
in address.component.ts  `@Input() experiment: any = {};`

Comment: @PierBJX check the solution and consider accepting if it helped.

Comment: Yes I wanted to get the value of child component to parent. Now it works thanks !

Comment: @AmitChigadani I don't have right to upvote yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `@Input()` property `experiment` instead of normal property in child component and assign from parent

```
 <address [experiment]="experiment"></address>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-pierbjx-pcgdpr)